# Can I have boolean buffer in OpenCL and change its value during kernel execution, example to break while loop

Tags: opencl

I want to do some experiments in OpenCL and I want to know possibility to change states during kernel execution from host code using buffer.

I attempted to alter the state of a while loop in the kernel code by modifying the buffer value from within the host code, however the execution is hung.

```
void my_kernel(
                __global bool *in,
                __global int *out)
{
        int i = get_global_id(0);
        while(1) {
                if(1 == *in) {
                        printf("while loop is finished");
                        break;
                }
        }
        printf("out[0] = %d\n", out[0]);

}
```

I call second time the function clEnqueueWriteBuffer() to change state of input value.

```
                input[0] = 1; 
                err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(commands, input_buffer,
                                CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int), (void*)input,
                                0, NULL,NULL);
```

Comment: You defined bool in the argument, but wrote int to it.

Answer (score 1):

At least for OpenCL 1.x, *this is not permitted*, and any behaviour you may observe in one implementation cannot be relied upon.

See the NOTE in the OpenCL 1.2 specification, section 5.2.2, *Reading, Writing and Copying Buffer Objects*:

> Calling **clEnqueueWriteBuffer** to update the latest bits in a region of the buffer object with the ptr argument value set to host_ptr + offset, where host_ptr is a pointer to the memory region specified when the buffer object being written is created with CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, must meet the following requirements in order to avoid undefined behavior:
>
> - The host memory region given by (host_ptr + offset, cb) contains the latest bits when the enqueued write command begins execution.
> - The buffer object or memory objects created from this buffer object are not mapped.
> - The buffer object or memory objects created from this buffer object are not used by any command-queue until the write command has finished execution.

The final condition is not met by your code, therefore its behaviour is undefined.

I am not certain if the situation is different with OpenCL 2.x's Shared Virtual Memory (SVM) feature, as I have no practical experience using it, perhaps someone else can contribute an answer for that.